# HSTS not working for default root path on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, hsts

HSTS not reflecting on my Tomcat default root url

I used below structure

We have configured the web.xml file with the following for HSTS and the redirect:

```
<!-- Enable HSTS   -->
<filter>
<filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>hstsEnabled</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>hstsMaxAgeSeconds</param-name>
<param-value>31536000</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>hstsIncludeSubDomains</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
 <init-param>
<param-name>hstsPreload</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
            <param-name>antiClickJackingOption</param-name>
            <param-value>ALLOW-FROM</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
            <param-name>antiClickJackingUri</param-name>
            <param-value>https://OUR_PRIMARY_DOMAIN.HERE</param-value>
    </init-param>
<async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>

<!-- Enable HSTS Filter  -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>httpHeaderSecurity</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: did you figure out the issue?